# Formula to deal damage - armor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formula

I'm just starting to learn c# and got stuck in this exercise.
I need to create a formula to deal damage - armor. The armor is reduced with each hit. If I write
`float damage = hp+armor-(physicalDamage-damageStrength)`it doesn't damage the enemy. The task says I should change only `float damage = ...' for this code to work. So, the mistake can be only in this line `float damage =`

````
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class Goblin : MonoBehaviour, IDamagable {

    static private string hitTriggerName = "Hit";

    [SerializeField] private float hp = 800;                   // health
    [SerializeField] private float armor = 100;                // armor
    [SerializeField] private float armorStrength = 5;    // armor decrease each time
    [SerializeField] private int n = 0; // number of hits
    private Animator selfAnimator;

    private void Awake() {
        selfAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void ApplyDamage(float physicalDamage, float damageStrength) {
        float damage = hp+armor-physicalDamage-damageStrength;
        
        if (damage < 0) {
            hp += damage;
        }
        n += 1;
        armor -= armorStrength;
        selfAnimator.SetTrigger(hitTriggerName);
    }

    public void onHitAnimationEnd() {
        if (hp <= 0) {
            Kill();
        }
    }

    private void Kill() {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}```

***Corersponding part of a "player" object***


```using System;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    static private string attackTriggerName = "Attack";

    [SerializeField] private float attackCooldown = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private Goblin aim;
    
    private float timeToNextAttack = 0f;
    private Animator selfAnimator;

    private void Awake() {
        selfAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    [Serializable] private class Staff {
        [SerializeField] private float physicalDamage = 100;   // staff damage
        [SerializeField] private float damageStrength = 5;       // damage reduction each time

        public void Use(IDamagable aim) {
            if (aim != null) {
                aim.ApplyDamage(physicalDamage, damageStrength);
            }
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private Staff weapon;


    private void Attack() {
        selfAnimator.SetTrigger(attackTriggerName);
        weapon.Use(aim);
        timeToNextAttack = attackCooldown;
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && timeToNextAttack <= 0) {
            Attack();
        }

        timeToNextAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

}```
````

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? We don't know the full task in this. For example is armor only working when you have armorStrength? Currently your armor is always active. Those are things that are required to know to really be able to give an answer.

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work"? what doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, armor is always active until it's broken completely. I've tried to give some more context. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong or didn't understand, but by quickly looking at the code, I'd suggest you declare the `damage` variable above the Awake function. And give it a 0.0f value by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made two unrelated mistakes:

- damage sould be only: float damage = armor-physicalDamage
- damageStrength should not be a parameter of the method because it should be applied to the staff physicalDamage after the hit, like you did to the armor.